# Divs move auto of the poisition on resize CSS

Tags: css, resize, position

i'm having a problem and i can't find a solution that fits, i'm have two divs and the second one moves out to below of the 1º one when i resize below 800px (1ºdiv width + 2ºdiv width). What i want it's to fix the elements (not position 'fixed'), but i want them side to side no matter what, like in the facebook page or google, when i resize they stay in same place even if they go 'outside' the window. http://jsfiddle.net/VLt9m/. Thanks in advance.

```
#wrapper {
padding:92px 0 0 0;
width:100%;
float:left;
}
#content a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#block1{
    background-color: #FFC374;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#b1Title{
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0;
    background-color: #FFD190;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
}
#b1Title h1{
    color: #222;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin: 8% 0 0 12%;
}
#block2{
    background-color:#449DCC;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#b2Title{
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#80B7D7;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
}
#b2Title h1{
    color: #222;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin: 8% 0 0 12%;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: ofc, Done. http://jsfiddle.net/VLt9m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish, you can do it with `media query`. But, here is a quick fix with `max-width`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/VLt9m/1/)**

Add this to block

```
max-width:400px;
width:50%;
```

And this to title

```
max-width:400px;
width:100%;
```

### Update

Give fixed width to `wrapper`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/VLt9m/5/)**

```
#wrapper {
    padding:92px 0 0 0;
    width:800px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but not really what i want, i want them to have 400px always and side by side no matter what, even if i resize below 800px

Comment: How can this be possible? Or do you mean `scroll`? The width should be `400` and scroll to see more?

Comment: it's like facebook page, the elements stay always in the same place even if the window has just 500px, they don't resize and they don't move out the place, it's like they attached to the background

Comment: No because i can't do it. But go for instance to http://www.w3schools.com/ and resize the window, that's what i want to happen

Comment: That's what I asked for scroll.. i will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is right, then you need to give min-width:800px; to Wrapper.

```
#wrapper{
padding:92px 0 0 0;
min-width:800px;
float:left;
overflow:auto;}
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/VLt9m/6/)

Comment: Thank you very much, yap it was that.